# Express a variable as a function of another

Tags: factoring

If we have this formula :

$a/(1-$$1\over x$$-$$1\over y$$) = 1/(1-$$1\over xb$$-$$1\over yb$$)$

Is it possible to express $a$ as a function of $b$, independently of $x$ or $y$ ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can transform the given equation
\begin{align}
a 
&= \frac{1-(1/x)-(1/y)}{1-(1/(xb))-(1/(yb))} \\
&= \frac{b}{b} \frac{1-(1/x)-(1/y)}{1-(1/(xb))-(1/(yb))} \\
&= \frac{b(1-(1/x)-(1/y))}{b-(1/x)-(1/y)} \\
&= \frac{b(1-(1/x)-(1/y))}{(b-1)+ 1-(1/x)-(1/y)} \\
&= \frac{b}{\frac{b-1}{1-(1/x)-(1/y)} + 1}
\end{align}
So only for $b=1$, the dependency on $x$ and $y$ vanishes, you end up with $a=1$ too, but for $b\ne 1$ the dependency is there.

Comment: How does your transformation helps you conclude that ? I dont understand how you get the denominator on the third line (seems to have a problem with parenthesis also)

Comment: Just splitting $b$ into $(b-1) + 1$. The extra parentheses are removed now.

Comment: With $x$ and $y$ showing up twice each on the RHS you could have the hope that they cancel out somehow, but the last line shows them showing up once each, only influenced by the $b-1$ term. You could also take the partial derivatives $\partial a/\partial x$ or $\partial a/\partial y$ and check if they vanish or not.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I see now